# Site logo on user registration email

Tags: emails

I am using drupal 7. I want to add the site logo on the user registration email, when new user added with my site. How can i include the logo path on the user registration settings. It doesn't support the html  tag format. I have also searched with tokens, but there is no token for including logo. How can i add the logo. Please help me.

Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score 2):

Drupal doesn't support HTML e-mails out of the box.  To do this, you can download either:

- [Mime Mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail)

or

- [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail)

You will also need the [Mail System](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module.  On my own site, I use the Mime Mail module with a PHP template that I designed (following the instructions in the Mime Mail documentation) to attach my logo to outgoing e-mail messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patrick, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Did you try?  What was the result?

Comment: @drupalfan When you reply to a comment, if you don't use the `@` and the name of the user you want to reply to, then the user will never see your comment. Instead, the user who posted the comment (me, in this case) will get the notification.

Comment: @drupalfan In any case, this approach does work to show the logos in emails; I use it on my own site.

Comment: Which of the 2 modules do you use: Mime Mail or HTML Mail?

Comment: @drupalfan Come on, read the answer.  It says "On my own site, I use the Mime Mail module" right there.

Comment: Yes, but there also we can read: "To do this, you can download either: Mime Mail or HTML Mail."

That's why I had to ask you, how you decided.
Thank you for your friendly answer.